# MATLAB matrix replacement assignment gives error

Tags: matlab, matrix, variable-assignment, dimension

I tried to update some part of a matrix, I got the following error message:

??? Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

My code tries to update some values of a matrix that represent a binary image. My code is as follows:

`outImage(3:5,2:4,1) = max(imBinary(3:5,2:4,1));`

When I delete last parameter (1), this time I get the same error. I guess there is a mismatch between dimensions but I could not get it. outImage is a new object that is created at that time (I tried to create it before, but nothing changed). What may be wrong?

Comment: I have edited what I've done. I travel all around the binary image and OR it with a structuring element. This time it seems fine syntactically, but it does not work. Do you have any idea about strel function of MATLAB? I cannot use a strel object directly as a matrix, MATLAB gets angry. I tried getnhood function of strel object, but no effect in the output image at all. Do I miss something about strel object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mention in one of your comments on another answer that you are trying to create your own dilation algorithm, and therefore want to take the maximum value in a 3-by-3-by-1 submatrix and replace the values in that submatrix with the maximum value. The function [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) will by default operate along the columns of your submatrix, which will give you a 1-by-3 matrix (i.e. the maximum values of the columns of your 3-by-3-by-1 matrix). The error results because MATLAB can't assign a 1-by-3 matrix to a 3-by-3-by-1 matrix.

One solution is to call [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) again on your 1-by-3 matrix to get a scalar value, which you can then assign to each element of your 3-by-3-by-1 submatrix without error:

```
outImage(3:5,2:4,1) = max(max(imBinary(3:5,2:4,1)));
```

Comment: Exactly.

By the way, if you think of doing this in 3D in the future, I'd first read the sub-image into a temporary variable, and then do max(tmp(:)). Thus, you won't have to worry about dimensionality.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to fill all indexed elements in outImage by maximum value for each column of rhs expression? You can expand the row you get on rhs with REPMAT:

```
outImage(3:5,2:4,1) = repmat(max(imBinary(3:5,2:4,1)),3,1)
```

`outImage(3:5,2:4)` works as well.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I want. After turning the image to binary I give up using max operation (it was necessary if I process gray-scale images). I use logical OR operation now. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

On the rhs of your equation you take the max of a 3x3x1 sub-matrix, which returns a 1x3 vector.  You then try to assign this to a 3x3x1 sub-matrix.  A singleton subscript is one with the value 1.  So the rhs has 1 non-singleton subscript, and the lhs has 2.  Matlab can't figure out how to expand a 1x3 matrix to fill a 3x3x1 space.

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, so I won't guess a solution.  Do you want to make 3 copies of the rhs and put one into each row of the sub-matrix on the lhs ?  Or are you trying to construct a 3x3x1 matrix on the rhs ?

Comment: I'm trying to write my own dilation method. As a warm-up, I tried to do take a 3x3 part of a matrix and assign the maximum value in that part to the whole values in that part. Thank you, your explanation is really helpful. I'm so new to MATLAB, I was confused at the basics. I could not have thought that max operation would give me a 1x3 matrix. I thought it would return a single value, but again, it won't do any good. I should think over it, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error before, and what I have done was defining the left hand matrix before. I don't know if you have the same case but you can try the following:

```
outImage=Zeros(M,N,K);
```

M, N, and K are the dimensions that you have. Then just type:

```
outImage(3:5,2:4,1) = max(max(imBinary(3:5,2:4,1)));
```